# 4k Video direct to GPU

Tags: graphics-cards, video

Is there a type of hardware spec on a CPU or any way in general to achieve this:  I'd like to take 4k video from an external source and input it directly into the GPU of my computer so I can avoid the "upload" time to the GPU

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no such feature, but the "upload" time can be minimized. What is your upper budget limit?

Comment: With 4x Nvidia Quadro RTX 6000 all interconnected with real NVLink (not the thing they say is NVLink on consumer grade GPUs) the uploadtime can be reduced for example.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by upload time. From what to what? What are you doing with the video stream once it's inside the computer?